# Override of Graphics.DrawLine

Tags: c#

I seek to `@override` the `DrawLine` method of the `Graphics` class, but I am unsure if this is possible?

I seek to put a validation in the method so that it stops drawing at a certain Y variable that I would provide, effectively adding a new parameter to the method.

Anyone got some experience or advice on overriding that specific method?

I am unsure about this rproblem so I dont know if I can simply do `@Override` and then give it a validation as it is plotting the separate pixel points.

Thanks.

Comment: `@override` is a Java thing. You're talking about C#, right?

Comment: Yes I am I have been doing both lately just confusing the two, I think you get what I mean though.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a separate method. Put it wherever you want:

```
void CheckedDrawLine(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int stopY) {
    // Do the validation, draw the line
}
```

And you could make it into an extension method by sticking it in a `static class`:

```
void CheckedDrawLine(this Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int stopY) {
    // Do the validation, draw the line
}
```

to do a `g.CheckedDrawLine(...)` instead of a `CheckedDrawLine(g, ...)`.

Comment: The problem with that way is that I am unsure if the method will take to it. In terms of I am worried about the Y increment of the program after it calculates the positions that need to be filled on screen it then draws them. I want to have a validation on that side of the method that simply stops the drawing at that Y point.
What you stated is a good idea but will not work as the Y variable to my understanding is not passed into a variable that I can manipulate or read while it is plotting the positions onto the Form.

Comment: @VasaSerafin: See that `stopY` parameter? You can add anything you need. It's just a method.

Comment: That still will not work. As I said this is not something I need to stop on the user's side (something they entered). I need to stop the method DrawLine form drawing anything past point Y on the Y axis. I need to gain access to the DrawLine method directly so that I may take the code it uses and use a method that will just replace the DrawLine method. The doing on the validation on the DrawLine will not work in this case as it is the Internal Graphics.DrawLine method. I would need to place my validation inside that method, which is why I need someone to tell me how to get to it.

Comment: From what I understand you want me to add:
void CheckedDrawLine(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int stopY) 
{
    // Do the validation, draw the line
    Graphics newGraphic;
    newGraphic = DrawLine (blabla);
}

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for normal code to replace method that is not designed to be replaced/overriden.

You can

- pre-process (i.e. ILDASM/modify/ILASM) all calling assemblies to use your new method
- replace System.Drawing assembly with your own
- use some existing framework that allows to override such methods like Moles or [Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you need it for unit testing.

Comment: Thank you. I will try do this, but I am looking to edit the DrawLine method, so I will ahve a look into the System.Drawing, I began to hunt for it jsut after finishing with the first comment.

Comment: You can't "edit code" of someone else assembly... Consider adding actual goal you are trying to achieve to your questions.