# Editing Graphics.DrawLine

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override of Graphics.DrawLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291253/override-of-graphics-drawline)

Is there a way to directly edit the Graphics.DrawLine method?

I wish to make some changes to the method, to include extra validations and possibly other things.

I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to? You should just wrap up the calls into your own method.

```
void DrawLine(Graphics g, ...) 
{
   Validate(...);
   g.DrawLine(...);
}
```

Comment: Does this include internal values that will be calculated inside the class? Also does this mean that I can store every coordinate that is calculated into an array while there is no code to do so inside the method? I need to stop the DrawLine form drawing when it reaches a certain Y value, as its drawing from one point to another.
e.g. draw from 1,1 to 1,20 if Y <= 15 //continue drawing if less then 15.

Comment: @VasaSerafin you will have to maintain that logic yourself. You really shouldn't change something when its *your* rules.

Comment: I need to change that to my logic, that is why I have asked. I cannot do a validation to encompass the method as the method is void, therefore the values it calculates internally I cannot access, until they are all fully displayed as pixel positions. Therefore if there is a way to change it I need to know.

Comment: @VasaSerafin `DrawLine` does not have much state associated with it. This was merely an example, you can modify it as you see fit.

Comment: You have confused me now. My question is; where can I locate the DrawLine method if you can point me to its code.

Comment: @VasaSerafin its internal to GDI+. you can't just tweak it.

Comment: I'm sure there has to be a way... I guess I have to code my own DrawLine.